# filter task scheduler tasks by taskname in powershell

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn "xyz"

I want to filter and choose some specific tasks from the task scheduler and if those tasks are present then perform certain actions. How do I apply this filter to choose more than one taskname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command will show all Scheduled Tasks on your computer:

```
Get-ScheduledTask
```

To Filter to just the task you need, you would pipe it to the Where-Object command. Example to show all tasks related to Windows Defender AV:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.Taskname -match 'Defender'}
```

Then store those task objects in a variable:

```
$DefenderTasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object {$_.Taskname -match 'Defender'}
```

Then you can perform an operation on the variable:

```
Set-ScheduledTask -Taskname $DefenderTasks <something>
```

Type in the following to get help and examples:

```
Get-Help Set-ScheduledTask -Full
```

Comment: Will this get-scheduledTasks command work for all the powershell versions? and how schtasks cmdlet is different from get-scheduledTasks?

Comment: schtasks is the old 'pre powershell' command line method of working with scheduled tasks.

Microsoft is moving towards powershell for everything, but you can use these older commands, or you can use the new powershell way of working.

Powershell also has a new way of creating tasks with the Job cmdlets (register-scheduledjob, get-job, etc).

Get-ScheduledTask might only be available in newer versions of Powershell/Windows, I can't say exactly when it was implemented.

Comment: I tried the same approch that you suggested using schtasks, but this doesn't work. I have a limitation to use old powershell version. Can you please suggest how to resolve this using Schtasks. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I don't really use the old schtasks commands enough to be helpful.

Comment: Okay. Np. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Maybe the script by Jaap Brasser you can get from the [gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Scheduled-tasks-from-3a377294) can help you then. It uses the Schedule.Service COM-object to query the local or a remote computer for scheduled tasks.

Comment: using get-scheduledTasks how to get list of some particular tasks from some remote machine?

Comment: if your computers are on the same domain, use invoke-command -computername -scriptblock {get-scheduledtask}